# Let $P(k)$ be the $k$-th first prime. Is it true that $P(k+1)\leq P(1)\cdot P(2) \cdots P(k)+1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, distribution-of-primes

Let $P(k)$ be the $k$-th first prime. Is it true that $P(k+1)\leq P(1)\cdot P(2)\cdot \dots \cdot P(k)+1$?

Answer (score 5):

Of course. The number on the right is coprime with $P (1),\ldots,P (k) $, and it's divisible by a prime.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 2):

If you're interested in [a tighter bound](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate), $P(k+1)\le 2P(k)-1$. Sadly, there's no $1$-line proof, unlike the one Martin provided for the original question.

Comment: Hmmm, interesting! Any tip for how could I prove this?

Comment: @IsabellaGonalvesdeAlvarenga The proof [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_Bertrand%27s_postulate) begins by stating and proving 4 lemmas, but if you just want a hint rather than a full proof I suggest you read the lemmas' statements, prove them yourself and finish the main proof yourself too.